# URL rewrite by keeping $_GET parameters

Tags: url-rewriting

How can I rewrite this type of URL:

```
https://example.com/assets/forms/vanilla/index.php?property=cus_F8fylX6aITpJOR
```

to have something like this:

```
https://example.com/forms/cus_F8fylX6aITpJOR
```

How can I access to the `property` and `vanilla` parameters after ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} to mateh the query string

Something like that :

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} property=(\w+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^assets/forms/([a-zA-Z]*)/index.php /forms/%1?$1 [L]
```